# ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'year' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

Not sure what's going on with my column name.

```
mysql> SELECT fullname FROM country WHERE year-independence > 1945;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'year' in 'where clause'
```

here is the table Limit 5:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| code | fullname             | continent     | region                    | area   | year-independence | population | avg-lifespan | avg-GNP   | form-government                              |
+------+----------------------+---------------+---------------------------+--------+-------------------+------------+--------------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+
| ABW  | Aruba                | North America | Caribbean                 |    193 |                 0 |     103000 |        78.40 |    828.00 | Nonmetropolitan Territory of The Netherlands |
| AFG  | Afghanistan          | Asia          | Southern and Central Asia | 652090 |              1919 |   22720000 |        45.90 |   5976.00 | Islamic Emirate                              |
| AGO  | Angola               | Africa        | Central Africa            | 124670 |              1975 |   12878000 |        38.30 |   6648.00 | Republic                                     |
| AIA  | Anguilla             | North America | Caribbean                 |     96 |                 0 |       8000 |        76.10 |     63.20 | Dependent Territory of the UK                |
| ALB  | Albania              | Europe        | Southern Europe           |  28748 |              1912 |    3401200 |        71.60 |   3205.00 | Republic
```

Comment: Can you try back ticks on the column?

Comment: \`year-independence\`

Comment: MySQL is interpreting `year-independence` as an arithmetic expression so it is looking for columns called `year` and `independence`. You need to escape `year-independence` using backticks to prevent this happening.

Comment: Another example of a poorly named column causing problems. Use realistic column names, and make them pretty in your UI. A good example here: `yearindependence` as the column name. When you need to display it, use `SELECT yearindependence as "Year Of Independence"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Certain objects within MySQL, including database, table, index,
>   column, alias, view, stored procedure, partition, tablespace, resource
>   group and other object names are known as identifiers. [...] If an
>   identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you must
>   quote it whenever you refer to it. [...]

as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (`):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
```

In your case

```
mysql> SELECT `fullname` FROM `country` WHERE `year-independence` > 1945;
```

You might've noticed I surrounded all the identifiers with backticks as it's good habit to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT fullname FROM country WHERE `year-independence` > 1945;
```

Comment: Hi @ChrisKehl I'd love if you could choose the answer as correct as it's my first time answering! Glad I could help.